# Excell VBA Check Date in Column header

Tags: excel, vba

Need help to add on to my macro.

Looking to expand this to cycle through each column header of the cells and check if date has passed, if so insert the "N/A".  It would do nothing to the range for the columns and rows for todays date and the future.

```
If rcell.Value = 0 and (Check if date in Column header this cell is in has passed) <-- Need help here
rcell.Value = "N/A"
```

The code will skip if a value is present i.e. 100%, 95% etc

Columns with all the dates are in range B1:NC1

A1 = User

A2:A22 are the 21 different items

```
Sub fillvalue()
Sheet30.Activate
Dim rcell As Range
With ActiveSheet
For Each rcell In .Range("B2:S22")
    If rcell.Value = 0 Then
        rcell.Value = "N/A"
    End If
Next rcell
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column header must be the date-type, if it is a string-type, must convert it by some code

```
Dim rcell As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each rcell In .Range("B2:S22") 
            If Cells(1, rcell.Column) < Date Then  <-- replaced now with date
                If rcell.Value = 0 Then
                    rcell.Value = "N/A"
                End If
            End If
        Next rcell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works very closely as desired. Only hiccup i see is that the column with today's date is filling in with the N/A also. MZ2:MZ22 I'd like to remain empty until midnight.

Comment: I switched out the "now" for "date" and it works as desired. Thank you!